# Not able to log into EE 2.9.0 when Cookie Consent is enable

Tags: cookies

I've recently updated a site from EE 2.7.3 to 2.9.0. A client has pointed out to me that she can't log into the CP but instead get's the message:

**This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.**

I didn't get this message using Opera but managed to repeat the error using Firefox (on OSX).

After much fruitless searching around and playing with session settings with the CP, I tried disabling Cookie Consent and suddenly was able to log in using Firefox.

The problem is that I really need to have Cookie Consent enabled because of the nature of the client's business. So I'm wondering if anyone has had this same problem and has found a work-around?

I'm also using the latest version of Cookie Consent 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having this problem too. What I do is, um, refreshing the form.

You may find this [bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20367/cant-login-to-cp-after-server-move-this-form-has-expired.-please-refresh-an) useful

Answer (score 0):

Also helpful is this bug report and workaround by on Github by diogomiguel:
https://github.com/EllisLab/Cookie-Consent/issues/2

(I found the line numbers a little off, with line 111 actually needing to be line 107 and line 98 actually 96)

> Cookie consent tries to clear csrf token preventing forms from being
>   submitted on newer versions of Expression Engine (tested with 2.8).
>   Possible workaround solution, is to add an if statement to prevent
>   csrf token from being cleared. If extension->end_script is called on
>   the same function, the problem will occur during the first submission
>   too.
>
> Temporary suggested solution:
>
> add to ext.cookie_consent.php (Line 111):
>
> if ($name == $data['prefix'] . 'csrf_token') {
>       continue; } comment out on same file (Line 98)
>
> //$this->EE->extensions->end_script = TRUE;